# ¿Cómo hacer en joomla una "single page" paso a paso?

Tags: joomla3

No entiendo como hacer una página en `joomla` donde al darle al menú me lleva a la información en esa misma página.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 

Por favor, agregue mas información en la pregunta sobre qué ha intentando y/o muéstrenos cuál fragmento del código no está funcionando.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola saludos no se que mas informacion agregar por eso especifique que soy principiante no tengo idea como se hace

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a las webs SPA *"Single Page Application"*. Para poder hacerlo hay que conocer bien javascript y el funcionamiento de CSS. No puedo guiarte en joomla, pero he encontrado ésto que igual te sirve: https://www.themexpert.com/blog/how-to-create-one-page-joomla-template

Comment: Gracias al parecer ya lo solucione despues de horas y horas de buscar informacion, ahora tengo que aprender a hacerlo en definitiva en puro html jej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes tener claras las diferencias entre un módulo, un componente, un plugin y un template en Joomla!, para ello puedes encontrar más información aquí: https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(general_definitions)/es

Voy a explicarte una solución rápida, tal vez no la más adecuada:

Creas un template básico, con las posiciones de módulo que necesites, acordes al diseño de tu sitio (funcional y gráfico), en el template puedes colocar los `id` en los lugares a los que va a llegar cada item del menú. Una mejor solución sería incluirlo en el chrome que define el estilo de los módulos.

El siguiente paso es crear los módulos con la información que deseas mostrar y ponerlos en las posiciones según tus `id` definidos arriba y tu orden.

Por último creas el menú dirigiendo cada item al id deseado, por medio de "enlaces externos".

Al final puedes agregar algo de animación de scroll para hacer más suave el desplazamiento por la página.

Comment: Gracias tratare de ponerlo en practica a ver si me sale, de pura casualidad sabes si hay algun tutorial que sea video de preferencia que haga esto?

Comment: La idea es que lo intentes primero con las indicaciones que te di, no conozco tutoriales en vídeo, puedes buscar en Google.

Comment: ok, lo hare, si no te consulto jij gracias

Comment: Parece que ya lo solucione la manera mas facil es conseguir una plantilla que sea single page. al crear el menu externo en el link pongo el ID que tiene que tener el nombre de la posicion donde puse el modulo y aparte agregue un pugin que se llama scroll To CK en el link type solo agrego scroll To y listo